# Spark 1.1: saving RDD in HDFS with saveAsTextFile

Tags: eclipse, scala, hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/linkage/out1
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:320)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:180)
```

when launching the following command

```
spark-submit --class spark00.DataAnalysis1 --master local sproject1.jar linkage linkage/out1
```

The two last arguments (`linkage` and `linkage/out1`) are HDFS directories, the first contains several CSV files, the second doesn't exist, I assume that it will be automatically created.

The following code has been **tested successfully with REPL** (Spark 1.1, Scala 2.10.4), except of course the saveAsTextFile() part. I've followed the step-by-step method explained in O'Reilly's "**Advanced Analytics with Spark**" book.

Since it worked on REPL, I wanted to transpose this into a JAR file using Eclipse Juno, with the following code.

```
    package spark00

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object DataAnalysis1 {

  case class MatchData(id1: Int, id2: Int, scores: Array[Double], matched: Boolean)

  def isHeader(line:String) = line.contains("id_1")

  def toDouble(s:String) = {
     if ("?".equals(s)) Double.NaN else s.toDouble
  }

  def parse(line:String) = {
    val pieces = line.split(",")
    val id1 = pieces(0).toInt
    val id2 = pieces(1).toInt
    val scores = pieces.slice(2, 11).map(toDouble)
    val matched = pieces(11).toBoolean
    MatchData(id1, id2, scores, matched)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("DataAnalysis1")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        // Load our input data.
        val rawblocks =  sc.textFile(args(0))

        // CLEAN-UP
        // a. calling !isHeader(): suppress header
        val noheader = rawblocks.filter(!isHeader(_))
        // b. calling parse(): setting feature types and renaming headers
        val parsed = noheader.map(line => parse(line))

        // EXPORT CLEAN FILE
        parsed.coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
  }

}
```

As you can see `args(0)` should be "linkage" directory, and **`args(1)`** is actually the output HDFS directory **`linkage/out1`** based on my `spark-submit` command above.

I've also tried the last line **without** `coalesce(1,true)`

Here's the official RDD type for `parsed`

```
parsed: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, Array[Double], Boolean)] = MappedRDD[3] at map at <console>:34
```

Thank you in advance for your support

Nov 20th: I'm adding this simple Wordcount code that **works well** when running the `spark-submit` command the same way as for the code above. Thus, my question will be: why the `saveAsTextFile()` worked for this one and not the for other code ?

```
object SpWordCount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        // Create a Scala Spark Context.
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("wordCount")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        // Load our input data.
        val input =  sc.textFile(args(0))
        // Split it up into words.
        val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
        // Transform into word and count.
        val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
        // Save the word count back out to a text file, causing evaluation.
        counts.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remove `linkage/out1` before you ran?

Comment: Yes, I did. I always perform a "-rm -R" on the output directory prior running the command.

Comment: I am not sure why its even going to HDFS to look for a file because you have given "local" as the master. If you want to process a file on HDFS, you have to first run the spark-submit job in yarn mode and then give the hdfs file paths for input and ouput.

Comment: @balaji: thanks for your answer. The presence or absence of `--master local` doesn't change the error message. I'm going to edit my post and append another (wordcount) code extract that worked.

Comment: first of all, you need to give absolute paths for both input and output, otherwise the relative paths will be taken from the directory you are running the spark-submit job from. My initial question was, why is Spark even trying to write output to the output file that is on hdfs, even though you say the master is "local". Are you sure you are running the same command you mentioned initially to run the spark job? The second code you shared is again, straightforward and it will obviously work as long as you specify correct input/output paths, which are taken from command line.

Comment: @balaji: here's the command `spark-submit --class spark00.SpWordCount sproject1.jar data/mr/mr00/in data/mr/mr00/out2` and it has both an HDFS input (with files) and an HDFS output (non existant) directory

Comment: @balaji: thanks for your patience. I do not understand when you say that it's "straightforward" for the second code, given that I kept the `setMaster("local")` in the code, and the relative path of both HDFS directories in the command. I've tried several combinations of suppress `setMaster("local")` and/or give absolute path for output: `hdfs://<host>:8020/user/../linkage/out1`, ... and still get this `Not a file error` for the output argument

Comment: @guzu92, you can not have "local" as master and give hdfs paths as input/output. If your master is "local", it will just look for files in local storage, and not on hdfs. For it to run on HDFS, you can give "yarn-client" as master and give it hadoop configuration by setting HADOOP_CONF_DIR in the path